# Odoo studio calculated HTML field

Tags: python, odoo

I'm working with Odoo studio , trying to set a html as a calculated field.
I'm trynig to embed a google drive folder with the following code:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=folderid#grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

And when I set it as a default value for the field it works as expected. However my problem is when I setup as a calculated field by getting the folder id from another field.

I have tried different ways but I always get the html field in blank, with no value at all:

```
url = "<iframe src=\"https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=" + record.x_studio_folder_id_documentos + "#grid\" style=\"width:100%; height:600px; border:0;\"></iframe>"
url = f'<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id= {record.x_studio_folder_id_documentos} #grid" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>'
record['x_studio_html_field_5TQIa'] = url
```

Both of the url options above give me the same result (and as you may see in the last image, I've tried setting it to a text field and it works as expected):

For lack of reputation, I add image links here, sorry:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWKGP.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im14W.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzQpk.png
```

Not sure if I'm missing some formatting or special setup specific to the html field.